# Dynamic components: Calling element by ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

One part of my application is an image gallery. When the user clicks on an image, I want to put an opaque layer over the image to visualize that it is selected.

When I display the layer, and I click on the image to deselect it, naturally I'm actually clicking on the layer. 
Here's the relevant ReactJS code to show what I mean:

```
{images.map((i, idx) => ( 
    <div key={"cont"+idx} className="container">
        <img src={i.images} ref={"img"+idx} />
        <div onClick={this.handleIconDeselect} id={"div_"+idx}></div>
    </div>  
    )
)}
```

I tried to give the img a unique ref (as shown above), but I'm having trouble selecting the correct img.

This is how I try to select the correct image:

```
handleIconDeselect = (event) => {
  var imgref = "icon"+event.target.id.split("_").pop();
  this.refs.imgref.click();
}
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

How can I select the correct image while using unique refs?

Alternatively, if the way I'm trying to achieve this is bad practice (I know you should only use refs when absolutely necessary), what is a better way to do it?

Comment: Do you have an URL so I can see the HTML / Javascript? Or maybe create a codepen.io.

Comment: I would say this is bad practice, you don't need ref to do this. You need onClick for your components which update the state. You render your component based on what the state is. An onClick for your image and overlay. Apply state update on click events. Apply rendering base on the current state.

Comment: @Kunukn yes actually you were right, thank you for the hint. I didn't think of that because I get the data for the images which I want to display from the parent component. I changed my code so now I save the data to the state as well and implemented what you suggested!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use state as here: https://codesandbox.io/s/m4276x643y
Maybe that is not the best way but it give you an rough idea.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";

const coverStyle = {
  position: "fixed",
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  zIndex: -1,
  opacity: 0,
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  background: "#000"
};

const coverStyleShow = {
  ...coverStyle,
  zIndex: 1,
  opacity: 1
};

const imgShow = {
  zIndex: 10,
  position: "relative"
};

const images = [
  "https://dummyimage.com/100.png/f10/fff",
  "https://dummyimage.com/100.png/f20/fff",
  "https://dummyimage.com/100.png/f30/fff",
  "https://dummyimage.com/100.png/f40/fff",
  "https://dummyimage.com/100.png/f50/fff",
  "https://dummyimage.com/100.png/f60/fff",
  "https://dummyimage.com/100.png/f70/fff"
];

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cover: coverStyle,
      img: imgShow,
      imgId: null,
      imgShow: false
    };
  }
  handleImageClick = (target, idx) => {
    // you can do something with this "target"...

    this.setState({
      cover: coverStyle,
      coverShow: coverStyleShow,
      imgId: idx,
      imgShow: !this.state.imgShow
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {"\u2728"}</h2>
        <div>
          {images.map((img, idx) => (
            <img
              key={img}
              src={img}
              style={idx === this.state.imgId ? this.state.img : null}
              onClick={event => this.handleImageClick(event.target, idx)}
              alt="dummy img"
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <span
          style={this.state.imgShow ? this.state.coverShow : this.state.cover}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```